# Load-Balancing on Fabric ensemble

Tags: esb, jbossfuse, fuseesb, fabric8

i'm Working on jboss Fuse ESB , i created a project that consume a web-service and get back a result from it, my application works very well 
i just arrived to the step of deployment , i have deloyed my application into a container under a Fabric-Ensemble that contains 3 Fabric servers separated on 3 three Server (Machine) at the same LAN , until this stage every things work very Well.

My question is: if i want to apply the high avaibility to my Fabric and activate the Load-balancing what configuration should i do ?

More details , my application is running(deployed) into a container created from a fabric server located on the first machine ( i have 3 machines as i said ), what if i face a problem with my first machine (ex:network connection broken) i want my application keep runing and automatically move to one of the others containers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use CXF to expose your webservices, you can use the Fuse Gateway  profile to create a reverse proxy that discovers and load-balances over all available endpoints.

See https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.2/html/Fabric_Guide/Gateway.html